# Importing data from csv

Tags: importing-exporting

Is there a way to do a partial data import, essentially updating existing data, without completely re-writing the entire dataset?

Comment: I am not aware of a module that handles that. You need to write custom code which checks existence of nodes by an identifier (e.g. `nid`) and update fields if node exists.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 the Migrate module has an option to `track_changes` in the source content. Which will then perform an update to previously imported content should the source content be modified over time. This is achieved by Migrate creating a hash value across all imported fields and examining that hash value on subsequent imports.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, import nodes for the content type from CSV file, try this module [Content Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/contentimport)